# Bernoulli principle and particle

Tags: fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

Bernoulli principle describes the flow of a fluid for steady, incompressible flow along a streamline. But it is said for a particle of a fluid along a streamline. My question is a particle of fluid refers to a molecule or a group of molecules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bernoulli is a continuum rather than a microscopic description of fluid flow. Where you have used 'particle' it should really be 'parcel' of fluid which indicates it is a group of some statistical representative amount of particles (e.g. molecules) which collectively exhibit macroscopic behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The Bernoulli principle is nothing but $F=ma$ for small volumes of fluid.
In other words, the only thing that can accelerate some fluid is a difference in pressure, and vice-versa.

A molecule of a fluid (since it has temperature) is moving quite fast, but it doesn't get very far because it collides with other molecules.
Those constant collisions are called "pressure".

If the molecules up ahead are at lower pressure it means they are seeing fewer collisions per second, so the original molecule will tend to get bounced in that direction.
So that's how lower pressure makes fluid move.

Comment: just a question, when we take a surface and we want to calculate the pressure force on it, I know that the particles of fluid are causing the pressure, but for exemple at a infinitesimal area (or a point like in a streamline) of the surface, is the small volume of fluid(containing many molecules) causing the pressure?

Comment: @Tonylb1: Suppose you take a small segment of the wall facing the fluid. It has a certain area *a*. It feels a force *f*, which is nothing but the impact of fluid particles bouncing off of that area of wall. The definition of pressure is force divided by area, *f/a*. So you can make the area as small as you like, or maybe not so small. The bigger it is, the more force it will feel because it has more area for more molecules to bounce off of. The smaller, the less, but either way, the ratio of force to area, the pressure, stays the same. You don't have to resort to infinitesimals.